# ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable in Angular Services

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have written multiple services to hit different APIs. The services written for post are working somehow but giving this error

> ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>       at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)

As for the services written for the GET method the same error is shown but i get no data in return. 
Here is my service

```
GetClientData(): Observable<ClientDto> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/getClients";
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    let options_ : any = {
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "blob",
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Accept": "application/json"
        })
    };

    return this.http.request("get", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
        return this.processGetAllPermissions(response_);
    })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
        if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            try {
                return this.processGetAllPermissions(<any>response_);
            } catch (e) {
                return <Observable<ClientDto>><any>_observableThrow(e);
            }
        } else
            return <Observable<ClientDto>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
    }));
}

protected processGetAllPermissions(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<ClientDto> {
    const status = response.status;
    const responseBlob = 
        response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body : 
        (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

    let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }};
    if (status === 200) {
        return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
        let result200: any = null;
        let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
        result200 = resultData200 ? ClientDto.fromJS(resultData200) : new ClientDto();
        return _observableOf(result200);
        }));
    } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
        return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
        return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
        }));
    }
    return _observableOf<ClientDto>(<any>null);
}
```

Cloud Function

```
exports.getClients = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    }

    else
    {

        let allClients = [];
        usersClients.get()
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    allClients.push(doc.data());
                });
                res.send(200, {
                    "data": allClients
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Error getting data", err);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you considerer what may happen if your responseBlob is undefined? in  `const responseBlob = ...... : undefined`

Comment: @MikNiller as a matter of fact i was also seeing this error during post requests `blobToText(...).mergeMap is not a function`

Comment: but my post requests were working so i paid no attention to it too

Comment: By inspecting your code it looks like you may be in trouble if `response` in  `processGetClientData` is not of type `HttpResponse `

Comment: @MikNiller i never studied too much about responses but right now i need to get this error to go away to move further. Can you please tell me what do i need to do?

Comment: What is `throwException`? Is it rxjs operator? are you using rxjs ver. 5? Make sure `throwException` returns an observable.

Comment: Which version of RxJS are you using? Does blobToText return an Observable?

Comment: @user2216584 i have changed my services code with rxjs ver 6+. Also i have edited my code and now the errors are gone but still i am not getting any data from API. Hitting the API with postman is returning me the result but not through this service

Comment: @WillAlexander see my last comment. I have changed my code according to latest version of rxjs

Comment: I hope you are subscribing the observable in the upper layers of your app code [i.e. Component/service]?

Comment: @user2216584 yes i am subscribing like this    `this._clientService.GetClientData().
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
      this.clients = result;
      console.log(result);
  });`

Comment: That isn't normal RxJS 6 code. I don't know where all the `_observable` stuff is coming from. Does `blobToText` return an Observable? Is an HTTP call actually made? Does the API allow OPTIONS calls?

Comment: @WillAlexander no they returned me nothing. Why is it that?

Comment: I'm sorry @ahsannissar I need a bit more detail. Can you answer all of my questions please?

Comment: @WillAlexander i have edited the code and added my cloud function here too. See if i have allowed OPTIONS call

Comment: Add 'OPTIONS' here: 

`res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS');` — your browser sends a pre-flight OPTIONS call. This may not solve everything.

Comment: @WillAlexander yes it did not solve everything even after i added the OPTIONS in the right place as asked by you. I am still not getting return anything in Obserable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197609/discussion-between-will-alexander-and-ahsan-nissar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```js
return this.http.get(url_, options_).pipe(
  map(data => {
    // Transform data here
  }),
  catchError(err => {
    // Handle errors here
  })
);
```

Comment: e.g. `catchError(err => EMPTY)` to let the stream continue also in case of error

Comment: I'd say it really depends on the implementation, because sometimes you want to return a specific type/object/value etc. when your request errors out. Doing just that at the moment on a client project, passing on a special string in case of error.

Answer (score 2):

I had same error in my Angular project. It was caused by an interceptor that was handling errors from API calls, and was not returning anything. My catchError function in the API call was returning this error.
The fix was to add this in the interceptor's error handler

```
return throwError(...)
```